# Why HttpURLConnection stops its execution?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I want to ping url with this AsyncTask

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private inner class ActivationAsyncTask : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Int>() {

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Int? {
            HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false)
            val activationUrl = ActivationManager.shared.getActivationUrl()
            val httpURLConnection = (URL(activationUrl).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection)
            httpURLConnection.requestMethod = "HEAD"
            var result = 520
            result = try {
                httpURLConnection.responseCode // trouble is here
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                520
            } catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
                520
            }
            Log.d("Tag", "This log never shows up")
            return result
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: Int?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            val response = when (result) {
                200     -> MainHttpStatus.OK
                401     -> MainHttpStatus.Unauthorized
                else    -> MainHttpStatus.Unknown
            }
            listener.completion(response)
        }
    }
```

But when I try to get `.responseCode` the task does not continue as if execution froze forever. What's wrong?

Comment: Since `AsyncTask` is deprecated, and since `HttpURLConnection` has an awful API, you might want to consider using a more modern HTTP client. OkHttp is fairly popular and has [built-in asynchronous options](https://square.github.io/okhttp/recipes/#asynchronous-get-kt-java).

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `httpURLConnection.connect()` method before reading the response code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: have you added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml file ? are you trying to connect to a https URL? If yes, in that case you should use HttpsURLConnection.